# Assignment between Typescript distributive condition type fail

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have some code using conditional types. Depending on the `command` key, I need the object to have to correct keys. I inspired myself from [this great post](https://artsy.github.io/blog/2018/11/21/conditional-types-in-typescript/).

This is my code:

```
export type EngineActionMessageKey = "load-library" | "create-context";

interface EngineActionMessage {
  command: EngineActionMessageKey;
}

export interface LoadLibraryEngineAction extends EngineActionMessage {
  command: "load-library";
  libraryLocation: string;
}
export interface CreateContextEngineAction extends EngineActionMessage {
  command: "create-context";
  deviceId: string;
}

export type AnyEngineActionMessage = LoadLibraryEngineAction | CreateContextEngineAction;

type CommandAndPayload<A, C> = A extends { command: C } ? A : never;
type WorkerCommandPayload<C> = Omit<CommandAndPayload<AnyEngineActionMessage, C>, "command">;

function workerCommand<C extends AnyEngineActionMessage["command"]>(command: C, payload: WorkerCommandPayload<C>) {

  // 
  // Error here
  // 
  const augmentedPayload: CommandAndPayload<AnyEngineActionMessage, C> = {
    ...payload,
    command,
  };
  console.log(augmentedPayload);
}

// that works fine, autocompletion works as expected
workerCommand("load-library", { libraryLocation: ""});
workerCommand("create-context", { deviceId: ""});
```

I need the `augmentedPayload` object to contain the "command" key, but I don't understand why I get this error:

```
Type 'WorkerCommandPayload<C> & { command: C; }' is not assignable to type 'CommandAndPayload<LoadLibraryEngineAction, C> | CommandAndPayload<CreateContextEngineAction, C>'.
  Type 'WorkerCommandPayload<C> & { command: C; }' is not assignable to type 'CommandAndPayload<CreateContextEngineAction, C>'.
```

[You can try it in the TS playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCiA7A5gSw8AQQGMYcIMBZYAZ2oEMtgBpYROAXjgCIAbCOgCYBaHjgBGUOlERc4AH25EowOjGBCi5NSBhcA3ACgDeNVABmdIqky58xUuSq0GqAN4G4cTQFtvdDAIAXOjYeIQkZJQ09IwsiIYAvkagkLBwJsDmlqgAMvwCOeKS0jZh9pFwoGoB1CG24Q5Rzoxw7p4+fgHBvPkiRVIyhp6iEgN5RKqRwdQwUHhYiQYp0PAZWVZwAMLKqsCbWlWldhHklTrANXVlJ00xbh5eEL7+QYo7ahoHOvoPAsAAbjgrABJV4zObYRZLcArBDIVAEDCII4NSJOO4cOB5QSFUYlULHRryLbvPZfGAo8rkQwGJAoLZPToCRECAAKdEQfEEAB4CAAaLYAPkxBDO1QEtVcj2eXS2cAScAA-HBRcF8P9MoY6agAOrQADWmX2MrZHK5Am5m2FnAA8t4cDBLYyXiz2Zz8rykZSbuiXAKrQKuB0XlxBTSzABXDA3OAAdwNRudAUtYouEpVXoJqMc0RcAG0g0mBFwALqCgAUwdlmwFYDN+WCeqghqgxqZbvNlsFAEpWg9NBgZnA6BGsN4LmpTe7BME2y6Ah2PYjkVmqbc-ULMW1PHAAHT7uvTgR8h7tIsnzwJIZwSAzX2McsjscT4BT82BgBUXG7UPjzcTJrlj0gh9HiMgClKIzFIg4yTOQ3RcAkP4GH+LZzgEQFKCoHwDtougQXAfyAiCrxcIhyFAA)

Comment: I'm debating keeping this open or closing it as a duplicate of [this question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/60194677/types-for-function-that-applys-name-of-function-and-arguments), because it has the same underlying issues with generics and correlated unions. Technically the compiler is correct to complain, but even preventing the unlikely-to-happen problem doesn't help due to the issue in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581); you might as well use a type assertion. By translating that answer here I am getting [this code](https://tsplay.dev/mq8BkN).

Comment: @jcalz thanks for looking into this, much appreciated. I will go with a type assertion in this case.